# Can't import this excel file into R

Tags: r, excel, file, import, format

I'm having trouble importing a file into R. The file was obtained from this website: https://report.nih.gov/award/index.cfm, where I clicked "Import Table" and downloaded a .xls file for the year 1992.

This image might help describe how I retrieved the data [image: Image describing how I retrieved the data from the NIH database]

Here's what I've tried typing into the console, along with the results:

Input:

```
> library('readxl')
> data1992 <- read_excel("1992.xls")
```

Output:

```
Not an excel file
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Failed to open /home/chrx/Documents/NIH Funding Awards, 1992 - 2016/1992.xls
```

Input:

```
> data1992 <- read.csv ("1992.xls", sep ="\t")
```

Output:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is relevant, but I'm using GalliumOS (linux). Because I'm using Linux, Excel isn't installed on my computer. LibreOffice is.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on how to obtain the necessary Excel file to reproduce this. If I just click that link and put in 1992 the result is a list of projects. I don't see anywhere to download an Excel file. Is it the Export Table option by the organizations list?

Comment: Sure thing, give me one second.

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a screenshot with text added to describe what I did.

Comment: It's just some messed up metadata in the excel file.  If you open it in MS Excel, ignore the warning about file type, and then re-save as an xls then reading it in works fine.

Comment: sometimes it can be easier to convert the `.xls` files to `.csv` and read the CSV file into R using `read.csv`

Comment: @LloydChristmas how would I go about doing this?

Comment: In Excel you do a file->save as and choose CSV as the file format.

Comment: see related issue: https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues/92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother with getting the data in and out of a .csv if it's right there on the web page for you to scrape?

```
# note the query parameters in the url when you apply a filter, e.g. fy=
url <- 'http://report.nih.gov/award/index.cfm?fy=1992'

library('rvest')
library('magrittr')
library('dplyr')
df <- url %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="orgtable"]') %>%
        html_table()%>% 
        extract2(1) %>%
        mutate(Funding = as.numeric(gsub('[^0-9.]','',Funding)))

head(df)
```

returns

```
                              Organization          City State       Country Awards Funding
1 A.T. STILL UNIVERSITY OF HEALTH SCIENCES    KIRKSVILLE    MO UNITED STATES      3  356221
2                     AAC ASSOCIATES, INC.        VIENNA    VA UNITED STATES     10 1097158
3       AARON DIAMOND AIDS RESEARCH CENTER      NEW YORK    NY UNITED STATES      3  629946
4                      ABBOTT LABORATORIES NORTH CHICAGO    IL UNITED STATES      4 1757241
5                            ABIOMED, INC.       DANVERS    MA UNITED STATES      6 2161146
6                     ABRATECH CORPORATION     SAUSALITO    CA UNITED STATES      1  450411
```

If you need to loop through years 1992 to present, or something similar, this programmatic approach will save you a lot of time versus handling a bunch of flat files.

Comment: Thanks, @Caffeine. The reason why I didn't scrape the web page is because I'm pretty new to R so it didn't even come to mind. Your solution seems pretty great, though. I'm definitely going to have to read more up on the packages you're using.

Comment: @GeorgeTye you're welcome -- If Hack-R or I answered your question please click the check mark to accept (both answers work, so I won't mind if you accept the other one)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
library(gdata)
dat1 <- read.xls("1992.xls")
```

If you're on 32-bit Windows this will also work:

```
require(RODBC)
dat1 <- odbcConnectExcel("1992.xls")
```

For several more options that rely on `rJava`-based packages like `xlsx` you can check out this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/).

As someone mentioned in the comments it's also easy to save the file as a .csv and read it in that way. This will save you the trouble of dealing with the effects of strange formatting or metadata on your imported file:

```
dat1 <- read.csv("1992.csv")

head(dat1)
```

> ```
>                               ORGANIZATION          CITY STATE       COUNTRY AWARDS     FUNDING
> 1 A.T. STILL UNIVERSITY OF HEALTH SCIENCES    KIRKSVILLE    MO UNITED STATES      3   $356,221 
> 2                     AAC ASSOCIATES, INC.        VIENNA    VA UNITED STATES     10 $1,097,158 
> 3       AARON DIAMOND AIDS RESEARCH CENTER      NEW YORK    NY UNITED STATES      3   $629,946 
> 4                      ABBOTT LABORATORIES NORTH CHICAGO    IL UNITED STATES      4 $1,757,241 
> 5                            ABIOMED, INC.       DANVERS    MA UNITED STATES      6 $2,161,146 
> 6                     ABRATECH CORPORATION     SAUSALITO    CA UNITED STATES      1   $450,411
> ```

Converting to .csv is also usually the fastest way in my opinion (though this is only an issue with Big Data).